# Heartrate count for a noob

Tags: python

My data set starts at `xmin = 0` (s) and ends at `xmax = 300` (s).
Below is the moving average calculated with counting the minimum peaks.

```
frame_length = 60
hr = np.zeros(len(range(xmin, xmax - frame_length)))
for x in range(xmin, xmax - frame_length):
    count_in_window = np.sum(np.logical_and(mintab[:,0] >= x, mintab[:,0] < x + frame_length))
    hr[x - xmin] = count_in_window * 60/frame_length
```

But I actually want a window that counts the minimum peaks for `x(0-60)` and then `x(60-120)`, `x(120-180)`, `x(180-240)` and `x(240-300)`. So it will be the heart rate per minute. I tried something like:

```
for x in range(xmin,xmax):
    if x != xmax:
        count_peaks = np.sum(mintab[:0])
        hr = count_peaks    
    x+=60
```

Im new to Python and I would be very happy to learn how to do this :) Thank you

Comment: You tried something like this... and? Did it work? If it didn't, why don't you keep trying?

Comment: I am still trying... I thought maybe someone here knows how to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `step` parameter of the `range` build-in function:

```
for x in range(xmin,xmax, 60):
    if x != xmax:
        count_peaks = np.sum(mintab[:0])
        hr = count_peaks
```

You can find more in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).